# chemfig/chemmacros: Line thickness of polymer brackets

Tags: brackets, chemfig, chemmacros

It seems that polymer brackets designed by `chemmacros` produce slightly thicker lines than the rest of the formula from `chemfig`. Is there a way to get polymer brackets with same line width as in the formula?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
    \usepackage{chemfig} %Structural formulas
    \usepackage{chemmacros} %Polymer brackets
        \chemsetup{modules={polymers}}  

    \begin{document}
        \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \chemfig{[-1]H-[@{a}]O-[1]-[-1]-[@{b}1]O-[-1]*6(-=-(-[-1](<[:240])(<:[:300])-[1]-[-1](<[:240])(<:[:300])-[1])=-=)}
        \makepolymerdelims[subscript={x}]{12pt}{a}{b}
         \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets are not drawn with TikZ. `chemmacros` just provides an interface for an idea presented in the `chemfig` manual. There the brackets are math delimiters, basically something like

```
$\left.\vrule height<dim> depth<dim> width0pt\right]$
```

*i.e.*, a zero-width vertical rule and an adjusted delimiter (similarly for the left bracket). This means you cannot change the line width of the brackets.

What you *can* do is changing the bonds' thickness with `\setbondstyle{line width=...}` (see the `chemfig` manual for details) instead.

Comment: Good to know. Do you also know the exact thickness of this delimiters for the adjustment of the bonds'?